# Sintaxe de definição de chave primária composta no H2 Database engine

Tags: sql, chave-primária, h2database

Estou tentando definir uma chave primária composta por duas colunas ao criar uma tabela no H2 Database Engine (http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), mas não encontrei no manual qual a sintaxe. Por exemplo: a sintaxe no MySql, Postgress... Talvez alguma funcione...

Eu tentei:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTACORRENTE (AGENCIA INT PRIMARY KEY, NUMERO INT PRIMARY KEY)
```

Mas o H2 não reconhece como chave composta (diz que não é possível definir duas chaves primárias).

Comment: Nada como a documentação: https://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
CREATE TABLE  CONTACORRENTE (
    Agencia INT NOT NULL,
    Numero  INT NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONTACORRENTE] PRIMARY KEY (
    Agencia,Numero 
 )
)
```